# Could you explain to me how to find the impact energy during the Charpy test?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, material-science

I've done the [Charpy test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charpy_impact_test) but I can't measure the impact energy of steel (0.4% carbon) and aluminium alloy (HE30). The specimen has a dimension of 10x10x55 2mm at 45°.

Should I use the red numbers or the black numbers to measure the impact energy?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be asking how to use a particular piece of technology. It is not asking about physics. ... Have you tried consulting the operation manual, or the laboratory technician, or the manufacturer?

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question as open because it seems to fall under [tag:experimental-physics] that theorists on this site are all too happy & fast to close without thinking more about it.

Comment: @KyleKanos : The issue seems to be how to read the dial. Any ideas how you might apply physics to answer that? It requires familiarity with this particular apparatus, or access to the operation manual. Perhaps also knowledge of the Charpy Test and the experimental conditions. And I doubt the answer will be of much use to the community. ... I am not a theorist, and I have thought about the question before voting to close.

Comment: @sammygerbil if you don't think understanding how to read an instrument is a huge part of physics, I'd be happy to have a discussion on that topic with you in a chat room. I'm not saying this is a *good* post, but it's not off topic.

Comment: I agree that this post seems squarely on topic. It displays a lack of prior research/effort, so I can't really object to it getting downvoted a bit, but topic-wise it is a perfectly fine experimental physics question.

Comment: The prior research effort would be to read the manual and find out which scale matches the OP's experimental conditions. Maybe it is as simple as a switch between scales on some other part of the apparatus. Having done that, there will be no question to answer. Or perhaps @DanielSank can answer the question? Of course ability to read an instrument is important - when you've got one that needs to be read. So is the ability to read the operation manual and to ask the lab technician. ... Lack of research effort has been used as a close reason before.

Answer (score 1):

After a short search I found this [instruction manual](https://www.dcu.ie/sites/default/files/mechanical_engineering/images/DMGimpacttester6706OperationalManualandcert.pdf) for a Denison Mayes 6706CE testing machine. There is a sketch in the appendix. Overall it looks different, but the dials might be similar. It also has 2 scales, ranging to 150J and 300J.

In section 6.2 (the Charpy Test) the manual gives the choice of fitting either a 150J *tup* or 300J *tup* "as required". I guess these relate to the scale. So select the same scale as the marking on the *tup* which you used.

The [Avery-Denison Universal Impact Testing Machine](http://www.globalmetals.com.au/_pdf/Metallurgical_Overview/section_1.pdf) (illustrated in Figure 6) looks more like your machine. The text says that for the Charpy Test the pendulum is released from the upper position and the striking energy is 300J. So if you have no choice of *tup* and have used the 'high' pendulum setting, you should read from the 300J scale.

---

*tup* = the head of a falling hammerlike mechanism
 [Farlex, The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tup)